# How to get the size of a dialogue in a resource without instantiation of that dialogue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

When creating a property sheet in MFC, I have to add property pages to it and then call `DoModal()`.  I've seen that the property sheet takes on the size of the largest property page, but it doesn't do that by creating an instance of each page.

Thing is, before the page is shown, in the `OnInitDialog()` function, I move things around and resize the dialogue (property page), but the sheet doesn't respect this as it never created the page.

So my question is, how do I get the right size of each property page to the property sheet so that it can correctly size the sheet?  How does the property sheet do it?  Is it somehow getting the dialogue size from the dialogue resource?

Comment: Yes. it parses the dialog resource. Set the size in your dialog resource to match the final size.

Comment: You need to access the resources directly and extract the size information from the resources header. Start with [`FindResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx) then [`LockResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047(v=vs.85).aspx) which returns a pointer to the dialog header (defined in a MS header file I don't recall at the moment).

Comment: Read about `PSP_PREMATURE`

Comment: @sergiol, thanks, looks like a good idea, but seems that each sheet window isn't placed and sized until it is brought into view. :(